# The product of a Hausdorff and locally compact space with a k-space is a k-space.

Tags: general-topology

The statement of the theorem I want to prove is:

**"Let $(X,\tau_1)$ be a hausdorff and locally compact space and $(Y, \tau_2)$ a k-space, then $X \times Y$ is a k-space."**

I am working with the following definitions. Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space.

1.- **X is a Hausdorff space** if for all $x,y \in X$ with $x\neq y$, there are $U, V\in \tau$ disjoint, such that $x\in U$ and $y\in V$.

2.- **X is a locally compact space** if for all $U\in \tau$, with $x\in U$, there is $V\in \tau$ such that $\overline{V}^{X}$ is compact and $x\in V\subset \overline{V}^{X}\subset U$

3.- Let $A\subset X$. Then **$A$ is a $k$-closed** if for all $K\subset X$ compact it happens that $A\cap K$ is closed in $K$

4.-**X is a $k$-space** if every $k$-closed set of $X$ is a closed set in $X$.

The proof of this theorem was found in the article **On $k$-spaces and function spaces. R.W, Bagley an J.S. Yang**, but I don't fully understand the proof

My attempt is:

Let $A\subset X\times Y$ a $k$-closed set.

Let´s prove that $\overline{A}^{X\times Y}\subset A$. Then for all $U\times V$ with $(x,y)\in U\times V$ and $U\in \tau_1$ and $V\in \tau_2$ it happens that $(U\times V)\cap A\neq \emptyset$. As $X$ is a locally compact space there is $W\in \tau_1$ such that $\overline{W}^{X}$ is compact and $x\in W\subset \overline{W}^{X}\subset U$.

Now let's consider the projection functions $\rho_1: X\times Y \rightarrow X$ and $\rho_2: X\times Y \rightarrow Y$ with $\rho_1(a,b)=a$ and $\rho_2(a,b)=b$ for all $(a,b)\in X\times Y$. **In the article define the sets:** $T=\rho_1(A\cap (U\times \{y\}))$ and $S=(A\cap (\overline{W}^{X}\times Y))$. **I don't understand why those sets are defined or what properties they have.**

Continuing with the article proof. If $K$ is any compact subset of $Y$ then $S\cap K=\rho_2(A\cap (\overline{W}^{X}\times K))$ **(I don´t understand the equality)**. Now, I think $S$ has a property such that when intersecting with $K$ results in $S\cap K$ is closed in $K$, therefore $S$ is a $k$-closed in $Y$. As $Y$ is a $k$-space, then $S$ is closed in $Y$.

If $B\in \tau_2$ such that $y\in B$ it happens $A\cap (U\times B)\neq \emptyset$ and $S\cap B=\rho_2(A\cap (\overline{W}^{X}\times B))\neq \emptyset$. **(Again I don´t understand the equality)** Then $y\in S$ and $\overline{W}^{X}\cap T\neq \emptyset$. Finally, the article states that "How $T$is a closed set in $X$ and $x\in W\subset \overline{W}^{X}\subset U$, then $x\in T$ and therefore $x\in A$" (**I don´t understand why the proof is complete?**)

I hope you can help me understand the steps I'm missing from this proof. If you have another suggestion please tell me.

Thank you.

Comment: Just as a meta question, why read *this* proof? You can get the same result proved in a cleaner way in Engelking's standard text, e.g. Less ad hoc and based on other useful results like the Whitehead theorem, and seeing a $k$-space as a quotient of a locally compact space etc.

Comment: It may sound ridiculous, but I'm interested in this proof without using quotient functions. The proof of the article is so short and I want to know the details that I do not understand.

Comment: Your definition of $S$ might be $\rho_2[A \times (\overline{W}^X \times Y)]$ instead so it lives in $Y$? Otherwise $S \cap K$ would not be defined.

Comment: I didn't know of that result, I'm going to proof that result. Well, the test seems to be based on closed. Thank you, really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original paper is [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1966-017-03/S0002-9939-1966-0192468-3/S0002-9939-1966-0192468-3.pdf), Thm 1. where notation is slightly different. I'll follow theirs.

To show $X \times Y$ a $k$-space, they take a $k$-closed set $C \subseteq X \times Y$, and we need to show it's closed, so take $(x,y) \in \overline{C}$. We'd like to conclude somehow that $(x,y) \in C$.

To this end they take any compact neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ and inside that an arbitary compact neighbourhood $U$ of $x$, so $x \in U \subseteq V$ and both are (essentially arbitrary) compact neighbourhoods of $x$ (here we heavily use the local compact Hausdorffness of $X$; I'm not entirely convinced we need both $U$ and $V$ BTW.). Then they define $$T=\pi_1[C \cap (V \times \{y\}]$$

where $\pi_1$ is the (continuous) projection from $X \times Y$ onto $X$ (and they'll use $\pi_2$ for the other projection).
If $(x,y) \in C$ would hold, as we'd like, it would lie in $T$, but for now we cannot say much about $T$ beyond the fact that it's closed in $X$: $C$ is $k$-closed and $V \times \{y\}$ is compact so the intersection is closed in $V \times \{y\}$ and hence compact too, and as $\pi_1$ is continuous, $T$ is compact too and thus closed (as $X$ is Hausdorff).

The also define an analogous set $$S=\pi_2[C \cap (U \times Y)]$$

Again, $(x,y) \in C$ would imply that $y \in S$ (but we cannot show that this holds yet). To show $S \subseteq Y$ to be closed they use that $Y$ is a $k$-space: let $A \subseteq Y$ be any compact set.

Note that $$S\cap A = \pi_2[C \cap (U \times Y)] \cap \pi_2[X \times A] = \pi_2[C \cap (U \times Y) \cap (X \times A)] = \pi_2[C \cap (U \times A)]$$

by simple set theory, and then $U \times A$ is again compact (product of $A$ and the compact $U$) and again as $C$ is $k$-closed, the intersection $C \cap (U \times A)$ is closed in $U \times A$, hence compact and as $Y$ is Hausdorff (here we really need it), $S \cap A$ is closed. As $A$ is arbitrary, we've shown that $S$ is $k$-closed and thus closed.

Now they reap profit from the fact that $S$ is closed: let $W$ be any neighbourhood of $y$, then $U \times W$ is a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ in the product and as $(x,y) \in \overline{C}$ (here we use it finally): $$(U \times W) \cap C \neq \emptyset$$

and so $$S \cap W= \text{ (shown similarly as before) } = \pi_2[C \cap (U \times W)]  \neq \emptyset$$

and as $W$ was arbitrary, $y \in \overline{S}=S$ (!).
It follows from the definition of $S$ then that for some $x'\in V$ we have $(x',y) \in C$ and this $x' \in T$ as well. So for any compact neighbourhood $V$ of $x$ we've shown (rather trickily) that $V \cap T \neq \emptyset$ and again we conclude $x \in \overline{T}=T$ (we already saw $T$ is closed) and so $x \in T$. Now, $y \in T$ allows us to conclude that $(x,y) \in C$ as required. QED

So it's short as written down but requires a bit of thought as to the correctness. The authors at the end refer to a different proof of this fact that was published two years before their paper and which used Whitehead's theorem (I suspect: the fact that $\pi_1: X \times K \to X$ is a closed map for compact $K$); a similar proof can be found in Engelking's text. But they prefer their own proof as being more direct. That it is; it only uses definitions and very basic facts (compact in Hausdorff is closed; continuous image of compact is compact) and some clever definitions for $S$ and $T$. But it took me a while to fully digest and I hope my "extended version" helps you a bit as well.

Comment: Your extended version is very good, thank you very much.

Comment: @Israel you’re welcome!